# поддержка псевдонимов или сокращенних путей git 2.24.1

Tags: git

предлагается файл .profile, но к сожаленью у меня его нет при установке.

поддержка псевдонимов или сокращенних путей, где файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Псевдонимы у git-а хранятся в .gitconfig филе. На пример:

```
[alias]
    pull = pull --ff-only
```